# 'Index was out of range. It must not be a negative value and must be smaller than the size of the collection

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
int secilenıd = GridView1.SelectedIndex;

GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[secilenıd];

string sorgu = "DELETE  FROM PersonelBilgileri WHERE PersonelID='"+row.Cells[1].Text + "'";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO;

Comment: Side note: use proper parameterization, do *not* concatenate data into your query, it's **dangerous**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Gridview Use datakeys in gridview control for better execution

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AllowPaging="false" AutoGenerateColumns="false" PagerStyle-Mode="NumericPages" DataKeyNames="datatableprimarykey"
OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" >


//c#
string PersonelID =this.GridView1.DataKeys[this.GridView1.SelectedIndex].Value.ToString()
```

Answer (score 1):

Cell with index 1 probably won't exist. Check your grid again.